# SQL Server : create a table where the columns are a row - index mod x

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2005, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table containing 2 columns - `identifier` (1, 2, 3...) and the value.

It is necessary to make a table, where as columns will be the remnants of division of identifiers by 3.

An example:

Table1:

```
id   value
----------
 1    aaa
 2    bbb
 3    ccc
 4    ddd
 5    eee
 6    fff
```

Result should be:

```
 0     1     2
----------------
aaa   bbb   ccc
ddd   eee   fff
```

Tell me please how to do it in SQL Server.

PS. whether it is possible to realize it not using an identifier as a separate column, but using only the actual row number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation. If `id` starts at `1` and is always incrementing, without gaps, then:

```
select
    max(case when (id - 1) % 3 = 0 then value end) value1,
    max(case when (id - 1) % 3 = 1 then value end) value2,
    max(case when (id - 1) % 3 = 2 then value end) value3
from from mytable t
group by (id - 1) / 3
```

Otherwise we can generate a sequence with `row_number()`:

```
select
    max(case when rn % 3 = 0 then value end) value1,
    max(case when rn % 3 = 1 then value end) value2,
    max(case when rn % 3 = 2 then value end) value3
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(order by id) - 1 rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by rn / 3
```

Comment: Cool, thanks!!!
and if you need not 3 columns, but 5, 10, 15 - can you make the recording more compact and universal?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but here is an option that you can dynamically define the number of columns

**Example**

```
Declare @Col int = 3

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = stuff( ( Select ',' + QuoteName([N]) 
                                        From  ( Select Top (@Col) N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
                                                  From  master..spt_values 
                                              ) n1 
                                         For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 

Set @SQL = '
Declare @Col int = '+convert(varchar(10),@Col)+'; 
Select '+@SQL+'
 From  (
        Select Value
              ,ColNr=(row_number() over (order by id) - 1)  % @Col 
              ,RowNr=(row_number() over (order by id) - 1)  / @Col 
         From  #YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(Value) for ColNr in ('+@SQL+' ) ) pvt '
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

```
0   1   2
aaa bbb ccc
ddd eee fff
```

Comment: @Zhihar Easy, we just specify the Cols in the final select ... Answer updated